# Optional extension points in plugin.xml

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-pde

I want to define an extension point in my plugin.xml which is not available in my target platform. This is fine for me, because I want to take advantage of it only if it's available .

However ,when I add it Eclipse flags it with an error

> Unknown extension point: 'org.eclipse.ui.trace.traceComponents'

Can I somehow mark this extension point as optional? I know that I can reduce the *Unresolved extension points* severity per-workspace or per-project, but I'd rather not do that for just one error.

The complete plugin.xml is

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?eclipse version="3.4"?>
<plugin>

   <extension
         id="org.apache.sling.slingclipse.preferences"
         name="Slingclipse Preferences"
         point="org.eclipse.ui.preferencePages">
      <page
            name="Slingclipse"
            class="org.apache.sling.slingclipse.preferences.SlingclipsePreferencePage"
            id="org.apache.sling.slingclipse.preferences.defaultPreferences">
      </page>
   </extension>
   <extension
         point="org.eclipse.core.runtime.preferences">
      <initializer
            class="org.apache.sling.slingclipse.preferences.PreferenceInitializer">
      </initializer>
   </extension>
   <extension
         point="org.eclipse.ui.startup">
      <startup
            class="org.apache.sling.slingclipse.SlingclipseStrartup">
      </startup>
   </extension>
   <extension
         point="org.eclipse.ui.importWizards">
      <category
            id="org.apache.sling.slingclipse.ui.wizards.sampleCategory"
            name="Sling">
      </category>
      <wizard
            category="org.apache.sling.slingclipse.ui.wizards.sampleCategory"
            class="org.apache.sling.slingclipse.ui.wizards.ImportWizard"
            icon="icons/sample.gif"
            id="org.apache.sling.slingclipse.ui.wizards.ImportWizard"
            name="Import from Repository">
         <description>
            Import a file from the local file system into the workspace.
         </description>
      </wizard>
   </extension>
   <extension
         point="org.eclipse.ui.trace.traceComponents">
      <component
            id="org.eclipse.ui.trace.tracingPrefPage"
            label="Slingclipse">
         <bundle
               name="org.apache.sling.slingclipse"></bundle>
      </component>
   </extension>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Can you post the complete plugin.xml?

Comment: So are you extending an extension-point defined in another plugin or are your defining a new extension-point that other plugins can extend?  I only see examples of the former.

Comment: @ChrisGerken I'm extending an extension point defined in another plugin.

Answer (score 2):

You are mixing two concepts here: Development time versus runtime.

Extension points are dependencies declared at development time. Therefore you should have the plugin defining that extension point in *your* target platform at development time. But you are right, you can generally write the manifest XML for extending that extension point without it being available. In practice this does not work well because many extension points require to implement an interface which itself is also defined in the (non existing) plugin.

To make the functionality be optional for a user (and to not force *him* to have the defining plugin), you need to make the *installation* of your plugin optional. But that is not related to the manifest and the use of extension points at all. E.g. you have to declare a feature containing your plugin and make that feature depend on the feature containing the plugin defining the extension point.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, it does make sense. The extension point I'm using does not require any interface. As a matter of fact it works just fine after I package the plugin. My target platform is Eclipse 3.7, but the extension point has been added only in 4.2 . I want to give the users of 4.2 the possibility to use the tracing page , but still allow installation on 3.7 .